# What is the implicit meaning of abstaining from voting at the UN?

Tags: united-nations, human-rights, procedure

Recently, India abstained from voting against China regarding the Uyghur persecution question.

What does it imply when a country abstains from voting at any of the UN councils?

[In the case of the UNSC](https://www.un.org/securitycouncil/content/voting-system), it means:

> If a permanent member does not fully agree with a proposed resolution but does not wish to cast a veto, it may choose to abstain, thus allowing the resolution to be adopted if it obtains the required number of nine favourable votes.

In plain English, it translates into:

> Neither do I agree with the resolution, nor do I care about it. Therefore, do whatever you have to do.

Can someone verify this?

And, what does it mean in the case of Indian abstinence from the recent voting at UNHCR?

Comment: I abstain from voting on this question. It doesn't mean that I don't care or have any opinion of its worth. For example, I prefer UN to UNO, the name of a card game, and a [tag:procedure] tag should have been used instead of the [tag:voting] tag, which is for electing representatives. I find generally that abstention without explanation implies nothing meaningful; but an abstention with an explanation may have some meaning.

Comment: That is just one reason to abstain from voting, another could be that they don't/can't publicly support something and thus abstain from voting.

Comment: It might mean "I agree but don't want to upset my allies or trading partners who disagree", or conversely. It will also most likely mean different things if done by a permanent member of the security council, and by a nation in the GA. This question needs to be more focused, as there is no single meaning.

Comment: This link is not accessible from Thailand. Neither directly nor through a VPN. Not sure what the issue is though. But I think it is very strange that the UN (the link appears to be from the UN itself) would define what the meaning of abstention is. Can someone verify the link and correct please? The question could be rephrased, but I think the essence of the question is good though.

Comment: @JoeyJoystick The link is correct, official, and contains the quoted text. It's in a section talking about the veto, so in context it's "here's how a P5 can avoid vetoing a resolution without having to vote in favor." It's not meant to say "abstention always means disagreeing."

Answer (score 3):

Abstention can mean a lot of things. A country might abstain because they really don't care, or because their UN representative couldn't get voting instructions in time and didn't have the authority to make the decision themselves. A country might also abstain to send a signal. Maybe they want to say "this doesn't affect us." Maybe they want to protest this even being brought to a UN vote, or protest some other thing (when the UN authorized military intervention in the Korean War, the Soviets were boycotting the UN because the People's Republic of China did not have a seat).

Countries also sometimes abstain when they'd be inclined to vote "yes" or "no" but don't want to actually go that far. This might be because voting how they lean would anger an important partner: if the US gives you billions in humanitarian aid, you might not want to condemn the invasion of Iraq. It might also be that it would paint them as too friendly with a country they're trying to keep some distance from: you might not like Russia's invasion of Ukraine but also not want to be considered Western-aligned. In other cases, it has nothing to do with the countries involved and instead has to do with not setting a precedent. If you don't like Arstotzka's arbitrary immigration system, but your own system has also been accused of being arbitrary, you might abstain from a resolution condemning Arstotzka.

Your quote is about a very specific situation that only comes up at the UN Security Council. Normally, a single country's vote won't decide whether a resolution passes. However, if a permanent member of the Security Council votes against a Security Council resolution, that *automatically* means they veto it. A permanent member can't say "we're voting no but we don't want to singlehandedly block this." The closest they can get is abstaining. They could also abstain for any of the normal reasons.

India is not a permanent member of the Security Council, so this special case doesn't apply to them. If India actively disagrees with a resolution they can vote "no" without vetoing it. The special case also doesn't apply in the UNHRC. By itself, India's abstention doesn't tell you whether they agreed or disagreed with something. You'd have to look elsewhere to see why they abstained. According to various [press reports,](https://www.indiatoday.in/india/story/india-china-uyghur-xinjiang-unhrc-vote-2009488-2022-10-07) the Indian Ministry of External Affairs has explained that standard Indian policy is not to vote on UNHRC resolutions targeting a specific country.

Comment: As an example: I believe Israel (which is completely dependent on US money) tends to vote with the US in cases where nearly every country votes a certain way but the US does not (such as whether food and water should be human rights) - but it votes with the US, rather than abstaining

Comment: Interesting, that bit about their standard policy about no-single country targets, esp. in the line of not condemning specifically Russia nowadays.  I mean, if India doesn't even do that in the case of their rival China, they seem to be pretty serious about not doing that in general.

Answer (score 2):

Every vote on the UN floor is, at the same time, a signal to the people at home and a diplomatic signal to other states. Both of these addressees have an expectation of what the vote should have been (or, maybe, would have been under other circumstances) and whichever vote is cast needs to balance both those considerations in to end up with the least worst answer. (In some cases even, the same vote will be interpreted differently by different countries and the voting state will want to not send the wrong message to either of them – an almost impossible task!)

As such, it is impossible to give a blanket statement on what an abstention generally means. One must always look at the specific case, the state involved, its domestic politics and its inter-state relations.

Unfortunately, I am not sufficiently familiar with the specifics of Indian domestic politics and international diplomatic relations to comment on the case you asked for. However, to illustrate my point a little better, I will refer to [UN Security Council Resolution 1973](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Nations_Security_Council_Resolution_1973) which established a no-fly zone over Libya in 2011 and formed the basis for military intervention into the civil war that broke out following the Arab Spring.

Brazil, China, India, Germany and Brazil abstained from the vote. Within Germany, this abstention was generally seen as a tacit ‘no’ to the resolution without loudly saying no. The government at the time was disinclined to use Germany military for any intervention and they probably saw no clear attainable goals. However, the population in general was in favour of supporting the Arab Spring and deposition of Gaddafi (seen as a dictator). Thus, voting no was a no-go. At the same time, voting yes would have been easy, as there were a number of yes votes including the three western permanent members and EU ally Portugal. Therefore, not voting yes was clearly a signal in and of itself and the abstention was heard loudly and clearly as a no domestically.

Conversely, Russia has a history of supporting the principle of non-intervention into domestic affairs and also one of opposing the United States in many such matters. The Wikipedia article mentions it had reservations about the no-fly zone and its enforcement. It would have been very much within Russia’s character to have voted no, while actually voting yes would have been almost unthinkable. However, had Russia voted no, it would have vetoed the resolution and at the same time there was Arab support for the intervention (see e.g. the yes vote by Libanon). Thus, when Russia abstained that was a silent yes (and was understood as one in Germany).

Disclaimer: The above analysis of the votes on Resolution 1973 was paraphrased from memory from an article in the German-language newspaper *Die Zeit* that appeared in 2011 analysing the sitution. I do not remember the author or title but I do remember reading its conclusion back in the day.